# JPA with JTA how to persist many entites in one transaction

Tags: jpa-2.0, jta

I have a list of objects. They are JPA "Location" entities.

```
List<Location> locations;
```

I have a stateless EJB which loops thru the list and persists each one.

```
public void createLocations() {
    List<Locations> locations = getListOfJPAManagedLocationEntities(); // I'm leaving out the details of this because it has nothing to do with the issue

    for(Location location : locations) {
        em.persist(location);
    }
}
```

The code works fine. I do not have any problems.
However, the issue is: I want this to be an all-or-none transaction. Currently, each time thru the for loop, the persist() method will insert a new row into the database. Suppose I have 100 location objects and the 54th object has something wrong with it and an exception is thrown.  There will be 53 records inserted into the database.  What I want is: all of them must succeed before any of them succeed.

I'm using the latest & greatest version of Java EE6, EJB 3.x., and JPA 2.  My persistence.xml uses JTA.

```
<persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
```

And I like having JTA.
I do not want to stop using JTA.
90% of the time JTA does exactly what I want it to do. But in this case, I doesn't seem to.

My understanding of JTA must be inaccurate because I always thought the beginning and end of the EJB method marked the boundaries of the JTA transaction (assume only one method is in-play as I've shown above). By my logic, the transaction would not end until the for-loop is done and the method returns, and then at that point the records are persisted.

I'm using the JTDS driver for SqlServer 2008. Perhaps the database doesn't want to insert a record without immediately committing it. The entity id is defined like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

I've checked the spec., and it is not proper to call the various "UserTransaction" or "getTransaction()" methods in a JTA environment.

So what can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: So, what's the problem? What happens if the 54th record causes an exception to be thrown? Have you made a test? Your assumptions are right: in case of a runtime exception, you will have a rollback.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in my original question. I have already tested this; over and over again. If the 54th record fails, the previous 53 records are still inserted into the database. This is a problem because I do not want those 53 records inserted into the database.

Comment: How does the 54th record fail? Does it throw an exception? Which one?

Comment: Location objects contain many required fields and must contain a unique name. Failure can occur if a required field isn't present or a non-unique name occurs. Theoretically, these types of problems would be caught before attempting to insert (by using a "front-door" validator class), but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JTA and container managed transactions the default behavior for an session EJB method call is to run in a transaction (is like annotating it with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)`. That means that your code already runs in a transaction and will do what you expect: if an exception occurs at row 54 all previous inserted rows will be rolled-back. You can go ahead and test it by throwing yourself an exception at some point in the loop. Note that if you throw a checked exception declared by your method you can specify what the container should do when that exception occurs. You need to annotate the exception class with `@ApplicationException (rollback=true)`.

Comment: As I commented up above, I have already tested this; many times. If the 54th record fails, the previous 53 records are still inserted into the database. This is a problem because I do not want those 53 records inserted into the database.

Comment: how do you obtain the EntityManager? If it is not injected you will need to call joinTransaction or manage yourself the whole transaction (begin, rollback, etc). My advise is to use container managed transactions and injected EntityManagers.

Comment: EntityManager is injected like this:    

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager em;

Answer (score 0):

if there was a duplicate entry while looping then it will continue without problems and when compiler reaches this line `em.flush();` after the loop then it will throw an exception and rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JBoss. Set your datasource in your standalone.xml or domain.xml to have 
`<datasource jta="true" ...>`
Seems obvious, but I obviously set it wrong a long time ago and forgot about it.